Set GMAIL as default email client Ubuntu 22 & 24
I see this flagged as DUPLICATE but can't read the reply anywhere. How do I set GMAIL as default email client? As recommended somewhere in this page, in SETTINGS,APPS,MAIL, the default THUNDERBIRD MAIL cannot be changed, no DROP DOWN option if I click it. So, what are the alternatives?Maybe the proper question is how to introduce IN SETTINGS,APPS,MAIL "another option", like GMAIL, as an optional mail client?

Where? The only reference in AU I have found is this question but slightly different to yours

If I right click on this page, a window opens and offers me to EMAIL IMAGE. If I take that offer,  THUNDERBIRD opens and the email that I send is through THUNDIRBIRD, not GMAIL. Any email link that I get is open with GMAIL, that is fine, no problems. So back to my question: I do not want to use THUNDERBIRD if I right click on this page to email it; I want to use GMAIL. How to set GMAIL as a default email client? As I described before in SETTINGS,APPS,DEFAULT,APPS,MAIL there is no option to change that default set to THUNDERBIRD MAIL.

Please don't use the comments for adding additional information about the question. Edit your question and put all the information there.

perhaps explain (in your question or raise a separate question) your reluctance to use TB as your email client. I've been using TB for all the time I've used Ubuntu (9+ years) with a gmail account (alongside yahoo, hotmail, and Orange accounts) and never experienced any problems.

There is no Gmail app in Ubuntu
At the Ubuntu OS level you cannot set Gmail as the default email app. This is because there is no desktop email app called "Gmail" in Ubuntu.
Use Firefox
You can set your default email app as Firefox. Open the settings app and scroll down to Default Applications. Select Firefox from the drop down list for Mail:

Gmail within Firefox
In Firefox go to the Settings page > General Tab on left panel > Application section. Look for Mailto and change the Action to Use Gmail.

Hope this helps

If you use Firefox
Click the menu button and select Settings.
In the General panel, go to the Applications section.
Under content type, search for mailto and select it.
In the row for "mailto", click the Action column to change the action.
Ask will always ask you about the program you want to use every time you use an email feature.
Using  (default) will automatically open the new message window of the operating system's email program (e.g. Thunderbird, Evolution, KMail).
Using  will open the new message page for your webmail service (e.g. Yahoo! Mail, Gmail) within Firefox.
Use another... allows you to specify an external program for Firefox to run.
Application details... allows you to view information about the application or remove webmail services that Firefox can use.
